# How to sort related entity in @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, sorting

There are two entities **POST** and **TAG** they are connected by a many-to-many relationship.

**Post**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "posts_tags",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
private List<Tags> tags = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Tag**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Posts> posts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Depending on which **Tag** I chose, should show me all posts dependent on him.
All posts should be displayed using pagination and sorting which user selects.

> The problem is that sorting and pagination are ignored.

**My first try**

```java
public Page<Posts>  getPostsByTag(String tag, Integer page, Integer size, String sort, String dir){
    Tags tags = tagsRepository.findByTagName(tag);

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page,size, dir.equals("asc") ? Sort.Direction.ASC : Sort.Direction.DESC,sort);

    return new PageImpl<>(tags.getPosts(),pageable,tags.getPosts().size());
}
```

**My second try**

```java
public Page<Posts>  getPostsByTag(String tag, Integer page, Integer size, String sort, String dir){
    Tags tags = tagsRepository.findByTagName(tag);    

    PagedListHolder pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder(tags.getPosts());
    pagedListHolder.setPage(page);
    pagedListHolder.setPageSize(size);
    pagedListHolder.setSort(new MutableSortDefinition(sort, true ,dir.equals("asc")));

    return new PageImpl<>(pagedListHolder.getPageList());
}
```

On the second try, pagination works, but sorting doesn't.
How to get **tags.getPosts() list** sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Try with OrderBy anotation

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
@JsonIgnore
@OrderBy("direction")
private List<Posts> posts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I need.In my case, I need dynamic sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Your first try seems to correct but you have two missing points as I guess.

The first one is, you should definitely make your query for getting posts from the post repository by providing the paging details.

The second one is in order to do that you should define `Pageable` in your repository as a parameter.

```java
@Repository
public interface PostDao extends JpaRepository<Posts, UUID> {

    public Page<Posts> findByTagsName(String name, Pageable pageable);

}
```

After that you can use your repository in your service like below:

```java
@Override
public Page<Posts> getPostsByTag(String tag, Integer page, Integer size, String sort, String dir) {

    PageRequest request = PageRequest.of(page, size, Direction.fromString(dir), sort);

    return postDao.findByTagsName(tag, request);

}
```

This will provide you the expected behavior with the abilities of both **paging** and **sorting** dynamically. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I knew about this method, but I had some doubts about it.Due to the fact that I have @ManyToMany relationship  I can search only in this way. **Page<Posts> findByTagsName(List tags, Pageable pageable)**.It works, but It seems to me that this operation will take more time.

Comment: What kind of doubts do you have? performance issues about the underlying SQL query?